# How to solve this question related to interest rate?

Tags: integration, finance

> An investor would like to have £5,000 at the end of 20 years. The annual effective rate of
>   discount is 5%. How much should the investor deposit today to reach that goal?

**I tried-**
 PV = FV/(1+i)^t

where Pv= Present value. FV= Future Value. i= rate. and t= time.

PV = 5000/(1+0.05)^20

**PV= 1884.447**

But this answer is wrong.

**Answer = £1,792.43** But how.

What is the difference between annual effective rate of interest and rate of discount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate of discount is $\boxed{d=\frac{i}{1+i}=iv=0.05}$

Now you discount $£ 5,000$ by using the factor $(1-d)$

$PV=£ 5,000\cdot (1-d)^{20}=£ 5,000\cdot (1-0.05)^{20}=£ 1,792.43$

Comment: Thanks... but I don't understand the difference between annual effective rate of interest and rate of discount? Could you please tell me.

Comment: At the link I tried an explanation. I hope it helps (It should help). http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342229/interest-with-inspection-fee-in-promissory-note