# Simple discount and effective interest

Tags: finance

Sylvia invests her money in an account earning interest based on simple discount at a $2$$\%$ annual rate. What is her effective interest rate in the fifth year?

The formula for effective interest rate is $r = (1+\frac in)^n -1$

The way I would do this is find $i$ which is $0.0204$

Then I would plug everything in $r = (1+ \frac {0.0204}{5})^5-1 $ and my answer is $2.056 \%$

However, when looking up solutions, this is what they did

They took $i$ and multiplied it by $5$ which equals to $0.1020$

Then their effective interest rate formula would look like this $r = (1 + 0.1020)^{1/5}-1$ and they get $.0196 \%$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how did you find i ?

Comment: $d = \frac {i}{i+1}$  $0.2 = \frac {i}{i+1}$

Comment: my thought was maybe you were thinking APR versus APY.

Comment: In case of simple interest the future value ($n=5$) is $C_0\cdot (1+i\cdot n)=C_0\cdot (1+i\cdot 5)$. $C_0$ denotes the present value. Do you agree ? Then the effective interest rate is $i_{eff}=\left(\frac{C_0\cdot (1+i\cdot 5)}{C_0} \right)^{1/5}-1=\left( 1+i\cdot 5 \right)^{1/5}-1$. Doesn´t it sounds logic.

Comment: $d$ is the rate of discount. See  here for an example and explanation. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1346195/144421

Comment: @callculus The problem states simple discount!  You cannot use compound interest formula...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annual effective rate of interest for year $t$, which we denote by $i(t)$, is the ratio of the amount of interest earned in a year, from time $t−1$ to time $t$, to the accumulated amount at the beginning of the year (i.e., at time $t−1$):
$$
i(t)=\frac{a(t)-a(t-1)}{a(t-1)}
$$
For the simple-discount method, we have $a(t)=\frac{1}{1-dt}$ where $d=2\%$ is the simple discount rate.
Observing that $a(5)=\frac{1}{1-0.02\times 5}=\frac{1}{0.9}$ and $a(4)=\frac{1}{1-0.02\times 4}=\frac{1}{0.92}$
$$
i(5)=\frac{a(5)-a(4)}{a(4)}\approx 2.22222\%
$$

NOTE: this exercise comes from the book *Mathematical Interest Theory*, 2nd ed. (Leslie Vaaler,James Daniel): ex. Sec 1.8 n. (2) at pag 65, sol. at pag. 441